# programmatically traversing a colour wheel and accessing either hex values or rgb

Tags: javascript, css, algorithm, colors

Using css and javascript I want to subtly change colour of text over time. This should be relatively simple using javascript.

However to ensure a smooth transition I want to have only small incremental colour changes ... hopefully the below explains:

[image]

The rough arrow shows the pattern of colours I want to achieve is their an existing algorithm for achieving these values?  Or any other method?

Comment: Use HSV and increment the *hue*. There are various to-RGB-conversion algorithms avaiable, search SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the colours in HSL and loop through the hue only

```
var i = 0
setInterval(function(){
    i++
    if(i > 360){ i = 0 }
    document.body.style.color = "hsl("+(i)+",50%,50%)"
},100)
```

Or a little more concisely

```
var i = 0
setInterval(function(){
    document.body.style.color = "hsl("+((i++)%360)+",50%,50%)"
},100)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use HSL colors and rotate the hue from 0 to 360:

```
text.style.color = 'hsl(' + hue + '80%, 40%)';
```